# How do i check if variable is undefined (declared but not assigned a value) vs undeclared (doesn't exist)?

Tags: javascript

Both result in `"undefined"`... For Example

```
var a;
typeof blablabl; //"undefined";
typeof a; //"undefined";
```

What is the default way to check if variable is undefined or if variable hasn't been declared;

```
var a = a || 3;
```

Only works if variable already exists in the scope.

Comment: `"use strict";` and `try` - `catch` assigning it some value?

Comment: yes, i was hoping to see something little bit less cluttering but if it is the only way then i am fine with it too

Comment: If possible, you could include underscore and use _.isUndefined(myVar);

Answer (score 2):

If you can hard code variable names you can test for the initialization of  some variable (e.g. `b`) without modifying it's value in the following way,

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var foo;
    try {
        foo = b;
        console.log('b', ' is initialised');
    } catch(e) {
        if (e instanceof ReferenceError)
            console.log('b', ' is not initialised');
    }
}());
```

---

Also note that the following throws no errors

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var foo;
    var foo;
}());
```

So if you're *"not sure"*, just `var` it again.

Comment: That trick without assigning testee a value is smart, indeed!   Is there an option to get the current scope and test if it `hasOwnProperty()` or alike?

Comment: @Serge well you could `.call(this)` but I don't see where a problem is with testing for the existence of properties, we already have lots of ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested my suggestion, seems to work:

```
"use strict";
try {
  b = 3;
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Caught it:", e);
  // Caught it: ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(a === undefined) will return true if a has not been defined.

(a == undefined) will return true if a has not been defined or if a equals null.

If you want to check if a variable exists, you could check the scope of this if applicable:

var exists = (this.hasOwnProperty('a'))? 'a exists in the current scope' : 'a doesnt exist';

Comment: Added an exists check as suggested by serges comment below.

Comment: `(function () {var foo; return (function () {return this.hasOwnProperty('foo');}());}()); // false`